# How can I send money from Stripe to my customer card?

Tags: stripe-payments

I want send my Stripe account money to my customers. My customers already have save cards in the system. I just want to money from my Stripe balance to their cards. How can I do that?

Comment: You can try this by using refunds [https://stripe.com/docs/refunds]. This only works if your customer have been already charged and you can set manual amount for refunds too.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but if this was possible without a customer having paid you, this is a  money laundering vector.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that.  Depending on your use case - you should [reach out to Support](https://support.stripe.com/contact/email) to make sure it's supported - you may be able to [use Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) for this though.